# CSS two stacked background images in divs, 100% width 50% height

Tags: css

I'd like to show two `div`s with a different background image, stacked on top of one another as the demo image shows.  How can I position these using CSS so that each image is 100% of the page width and only 50% of the page height?

Every approach I've tried so far automatically cuts out a large portion of each image, or I'm stuck using fixed dimensions which I don't want to do (ideally this scales well, regardless of screen size)

[image]

**Attempt 1:**

```
.home_image_one {
    background: url("party3a.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  height:50%;
  width:100%;
}

.home_image_two {
    background: url("party2a.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  height:50%;
  width:100%;
  top:50%;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<section class="row home_images">
        <div class="home_image_one">
        </div>
        <div class="home_image_two">
        </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Please provide html/css for what you have attempted.

Comment: Just to clarify, is that 100% (50% + 50%) of the remaining height after the space occupied by header? So `100% - header height` as it were?

Comment: Edited the question with my current attempt @dwreck08. Jaunt - yes, 100% minus the header height

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve something like you want using `position: absolute;`:

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7nc4ds1q/1/)

```
header {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    background: blue;
}

/* 
Set the starting top position of the wrapper 
to equal the header of the header and the bottom
as 0.
*/
.home_images {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
/* Make each of the children 50% height of the wrap */
.home_image_one {
    background: url("http://www.nasa.gov/centers/goddard/images/content/638831main_globe_east_2048.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    height:50%;
    width:100%;
}
.home_image_two {
    background: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/97/The_Earth_seen_from_Apollo_17.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    height:50%;
    width:100%;
    top:50%;
}
```

And if you want the page to have content below that, wrap all that in a div and give the div `position: realtive;`:

[JS Fiddle - Wrapped](http://jsfiddle.net/7nc4ds1q/3/)

Comment: This nailed it, thank you! I wasn't using `position:absolute` on the outer image container - that fixed it

Answer (score 1):

Set your header to a % and divide the image backgrounds between the remainder. It is background: url('images') instead of url-image.

```
body{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

header{
  height: 20%;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.home_image_one {
    background: url("party3a.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed; 
    display: inline-block;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  height:40%;
  width:100%;
}

.home_image_two {
    background: url("party2a.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed; 
    display: inline-block;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  height:40%;
  width:100%;
}
```